# Lactate feeling

Tags: training

Something i noticed on my climbs is that i really struggle the first 4 5 km. I feel very uncomfortable and at some point its like my body gets used to the lactate. It's like a switch. I can ride literally out of the saddle with high wattage relative to me for few minutes, after which i can sit down with no problems to keep a decent wattage. Any one with the same observations ? What if i do a warm up in the morning with some high intensity to get lactate in my muscles and in the afternoon do the climb, do you think that's a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the climb - approaching the climb too fast could build up lactate faster than your muscles can clear it down. But your blood vessels dilate to increase blood supply to and from the muscles during the harder work - it could be the effect you are seeing later on in the climb.

My understanding of the difference between fast twitch and slow twitch muscle fibre... Fast twitch are great for bursts of speed and sprints but build lactate fast. Slow twitch are better adapted to endurance & the steady grind. Slow twitch fibre also has a better blood supply which makes them great for clearing down of lactate build-up.

So, ease into a climb. Find your own steady pace and rhythm. Alternate riding position from in to out of saddle to recruit different muscle groups in the legs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the physiological reasons but that does happen. Also, sometimes I go for a strava segment uphill, so I warm up, say 15 minutes... Well, I have started to go hard on the warm up, and longer, because I get better results coming back from an hour ride of some 40 minutes uphill, then hitting the segment, than if I go fresh with a 15 minutes warm up

Comment: Same here. I find that it takes me well over 30 minutes or so at a moderate pace to fully warm up. A short warm up period just doesn't do it anywhere near as well.